# Why Linearlayout needs to be wrapped in scrollview to make it scrollable.?

Tags: android

Why can't setting the view's xml attribute `android:scrollbars="horizontal|vertical"` make LinearLayout scrollable.?

Answer (score 2):

Basically, setting the view's `android:scrollbars` attribute makes it scrollable, but the view is not able to interpret any user feedback.  In other words, the view can be scrolled with code, but not by touching the view on the device.

The `ScrollView` container is used because it provides a wrapper for its children objects, and propagates scroll touch events down to the children views.  So to conclude, while Views are technically scrollable, only `ScrollView` Views have built-in touch scroll handling.

Answer (score 0):

that thread is for TextView. In this case, ListView doesn't have setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod()) method.